# Libgdx Scene2d Progress Bar never empty

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I've been searching around for help for a while now.  Finally it seems quicker to ask than to keep hunting.

[Progress bar not empty at 0 value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvNpm.png)

Here we can see that even at value 0, the knob of the progress bar is still visible.  Since the player is dead, this should be empty.  I'd really like to use the scene2d progressbar class, anyone have any tips?

Here's the code for the progress bar:

```
healthbarTex = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Spritesheets/healthbar.png"));

textureBar = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(healthbarTex));

ProgressBar.ProgressBarStyle barStyle = new ProgressBar.ProgressBarStyle(skin.newDrawable("white", Color.DARK_GRAY), textureBar);

barStyle.knobBefore = barStyle.knob;

barStyle.background = skin.newDrawable("white", Color.BLACK);

bar = new ProgressBar(0, 100, .5f, false, barStyle);

//Animate duration is how slow the bar moves when updated

bar.setAnimateDuration(1);

bar.setWidth(100);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem, as progress bar is just a slider, it puts the bar at 0. The way I solved it was to create an exact copy of healthbar.png (same dimensions) in an image editor but make it a transarent blank png

```
invisHealthbarTex = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Spritesheets/invishealthbar.png"));

invisTextureBar = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(invisHealthbarTex));
```

Then whenever you update your bar progress, if `getValue()` is 0, set `bar.getStyle().knob = invisTextureBar` else set it to `textureBar`.

```
onUpdate(float val)
{
    if (val == 0)
    {
        bar.getStyle().knob = invisTextureBar;
    } 
    else 
    {
        bar.getStyle().knob = textureBar;
    }

    bar.getStyle().knobBefore = bar.getStyle().knob;

    bar.setValue(val);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  This will even make it easy to add flashing effects to the health bar!